# Query DTO with DTO collection NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, alias, fetch, dto

I have ObjectA (with corresponding ObjectADTO) with collection of ObjectB (with corresponding ObjectBDTO).
How can I query all ObjectA with join on ObjectB and map them both into DTOs?
I really don`t want to query everything from db.

```
    class ObjectA {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Garbage { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ObjectB> Collection { get; set; }
    }

    class ObjectB {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Garbage { get; set; }
        public ObjectA Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

// MAPS to =>

```
    class ObjectADTO {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ObjectBDTO> Collection { get; set; }
    }

    class ObjectBDTO {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObjectADTO Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this:

```
ObjectB objectBAlias = null;
var query = _session.QueryOver<ObjectA>()
.JoinAlias(x=>x.Collection, ()=> objectBAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.List();

var list = query.Select(x=>new ObjectADTO
{
   Name=x.Name,
   Children=x.Collection.Select(c=>new ObjectBDTO {Name=c.Name, Parent=x).ToList()
})
.ToList();
```

Didn't check the syntax in VS, but you get the idea